# JSONDecodeError: Extra data: line 2 column 1 (char 652)

Tags: python, json, pandas, dataframe

I am trying to load the json file and create data frame in pandas. But I am getting the json encode issue.
I have tried to find the solution but couldn’t find any. Please let me know where I am making the mistake.

Below is the code:

```
path = ""
def get_functions():
    json_files = [json_file for json_file in os.listdir(path)]
    datas = []
    for index, js in enumerate(json_files):
        with io.open(os.path.join(path, js)) as json_file:
            json_text = json.load(json_file)
            data = json_normalize(json_text['skills']) 
            datas.append(data['skill'].str.replace(',', '').tolist())
    return datas
datas = get_functions()
```

Getting the below error:

```
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
JSONDecodeError                           Traceback (most recent call last)
~\AppData\Local\Temp\ipykernel_16532\1003085653.py in <module>
      1 with open(r"C:\Users\manas\Documents\Master Thesis\Talent_dataset\data\UM_talent_dataset.json") as file:
----> 2     data = json.load(file)

~\anaconda3\lib\json\__init__.py in load(fp, cls, object_hook, parse_float, parse_int, parse_constant, object_pairs_hook, **kw)
    294         cls=cls, object_hook=object_hook,
    295         parse_float=parse_float, parse_int=parse_int,
--> 296         parse_constant=parse_constant, object_pairs_hook=object_pairs_hook, **kw)
    297 
    298 

~\anaconda3\lib\json\__init__.py in loads(s, encoding, cls, object_hook, parse_float, parse_int, parse_constant, object_pairs_hook, **kw)
    346             parse_int is None and parse_float is None and
    347             parse_constant is None and object_pairs_hook is None and not kw):
--> 348         return _default_decoder.decode(s)
    349     if cls is None:
    350         cls = JSONDecoder

~\anaconda3\lib\json\decoder.py in decode(self, s, _w)
    338         end = _w(s, end).end()
    339         if end != len(s):
--> 340             raise JSONDecodeError("Extra data", s, end)
    341         return obj
    342 

JSONDecodeError: Extra data: line 2 column 1 (char 652)
```

Data format as below:

```
{"id": "12345-wevbhgfh-234", "location": {"city": "Gilze", "country": "Netherlands", "longitude": 4.941387176513672, "latitude": 51.544281005859375}, "educations": [], "work_experiences": [{"title": "Directeur", "company_name": "Home grown netherlands", "location": {"city": null, "country": null, "longitude": null, "latitude": null}, "start_date": null, "end_date": null, "classification": {"function_type": "Managing directors and chief executives", "function_type_id": 1567834, "function_cat": "Senior managers", "function_cat_id": 1567511, "level": 8}}], "skills": [], "languages": [], "certificates": [], "working_years": null}
```

```
{"id": "2c03830b-1993-47f9-ab50-5df8542ca7cf", "location": {"city": "Harlingen", "country": "Netherlands", "longitude": 5.279466152191162, "latitude": 53.127471923828125}, "educations": [], "work_experiences": [], "skills": [{"skill": "Dredging", "skill_id": null, "skill_type_id": null}, {"skill": "Maritime Operations", "skill_id": 1588635, "skill_type_id": 954032}, {"skill": "Management", "skill_id": null, "skill_type_id": null}, {"skill": "Maritime Security", "skill_id": 7547637, "skill_type_id": 954009}, {"skill": "Maritime", "skill_id": 1588628, "skill_type_id": 953914}, {"skill": "ISM", "skill_id": null, "skill_type_id": null}, {"skill": "Offshore", "skill_id": 974784, "skill_type_id": 954132}, {"skill": "Offshore Oil & Gas", "skill_id": 974186, "skill_type_id": 953937}, {"skill": "Maintenance Management", "skill_id": 1589120, "skill_type_id": 953978}, {"skill": "AMOS", "skill_id": 954568, "skill_type_id": 1587125}], "languages": [{"language": "Dutch", "proficiency": "native or bilingual proficiency"}, {"language": "English", "proficiency": "professional working proficiency"}], "certificates": [], "working_years": null}
```

Comment: Does your json file contain more than 1 json top-level object? If so, try splitting them into separate files, as json does not allow for more than 1 top-level object per file.

Comment: Your recent edit looks like there are two separate samples. Are these actually just adjacent input lines belonging to a single sample? (And then doesn't the previous comment already tell you what's wrong?)